# Simple queue with Celery and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to implement a simple queue that performs one task at a time. Offloading tasks off the main thread using Celery and setting concurrency=1 in the Celery config works fine, but I might want to use more concurrent workers for other tasks.

Is there a way to tell Celery or RabbitMQ to not use multiple concurrent workers for a task (except by forcing concurrency=1)? I can't find anything in the documentation but maybe these tools are not designed for a linear queue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a separate queue for each type of task. Create separate workers that consume from each queue, with concurrency set to 1.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently doing that (concurrency=1). Good point about creating multiple workers, I guess that's the best solution to this problem. Thanks!